# Edit current form wizard to successfully post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using a css framework for a form wizard. At the end of the wizard it displays a message on the current page. I need the page to redirect to a `postData.php` page instead and am having issues with the javascript. Below is the relevant code.

```
<div class="step-content row-fluid position-relative" id="step-container">
    <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">
        <h3 class="lighter block green">What Services Are Needed?</h3>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action = "http://path/postDataPage.php" id="validation-form" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                    <div>
                        <label class="blue">
                            <input name="radPag1" value="1" type="radio" class="ace" />
                            <span class="lbl">Radio Option</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="step-pane" id="step2">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                    <div>
                        <label class="blue">
                            <input name="radPag2" value="1" type="radio" class="ace" />
                            <span class="lbl">Radio Option</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid wizard-actions">
    <button class="btn btn-prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-next" data-last="Finish ">Next</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var $validation = false;
        $('#fuelux-wizard').ace_wizard().on('change' , function(e, info){
            if(info.step == 1 && $validation) {
                if(!$('#validation-form').valid()) return false;
                }
            }).on('finished', function(e) {
                bootbox.dialog({
                    message: "Thank you! Your information was successfully saved!", 
                    buttons: {
                        "success" : {
                            "label" : "OK",
                            "className" : "btn-sm btn-primary"
                        }
                    }
                });
            }).on('stepclick', function(e){
                //return false;//prevent clicking on steps
            });
        $('#modal-wizard .modal-header').ace_wizard();
        $('#modal-wizard .wizard-actions .btn[data-dismiss=modal]').removeAttr('disabled');
    })
</script>
```

Can anybody give some advice as to how to adjust the javascript so that at the end it sends the data to the next page?

Comment: I don't get it, there are strange calls to `ace_wizard()`, a global `bootbox` variable... this css framework of which you speak of, what is it, and why isn't it in a tag

Comment: Here. From wrapbootstrap http://192.69.216.111/themes/preview/ace/form-wizard.html and for a less sketchy looking link https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR

Comment: you payed for that template, have they not helped you? Sorry, I have to ask, if I bought something and couldn't make it work, wouldn't I go straight to the vendor for answers?

Comment: Sent an email. I'm a total js idiot so I figured I was missing something obvious

Comment: ok, I'll look into it but I don't know if I'll be able to tap that vendor specific functionality

Comment: I'm sorry to say I won't be able to help you. This is a vendor specific issue and they state clearly at the bottom _"Please note that support is provided via email as mentioned in the documentation page."_

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var $validation = false;
        $('#fuelux-wizard').ace_wizard().on('change' , function(e, info){
            if(info.step == 1 && $validation) {
                if(!$('#validation-form').valid()) return false;
                }
            }).on('finished', function(e) {
                $('#validation-form').submit();
           }).on('stepclick', function(e){
               //return false;//prevent clicking on steps
           });
       $('#modal-wizard .modal-header').ace_wizard();
       $('#modal-wizard .wizard-actions .btn[data-dismiss=modal]').removeAttr('disabled');
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is not necessary, and window.location.replace(...) will best simulate an HTTP redirect.

// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect

```
window.location.replace("postData.php");
```

// similar behavior as clicking on a link

```
window.location.href = "postData.php";
```

Comment: I did try those as I saw them referenced on another stack overflow question however neither one seemed to carry the post data. Though I may have done something wrong.

Comment: Check this code and steps : http://heathesh.com/post/2010/05/06/Filtering-or-searching-an-HTML-table-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: I don't think you've read what this guy is trying to do. He's making form submisions and switching pages